# headphone/Microphone is not workingLinux mint 15

Tags: linux, linux-mint, audio

I was using windows and my headphone and speaker was working fine there. Recently I moved to linux mint and having problem to get sound on headphone. Speaker still working fine. I have tried several online solution nothing work for me. When I connect on front panel I can hear sound on my header but my microphone is not working that time. I can't use skype. For that also I have tried few solutions. I was unable to use my microphone. So I switched to rear panel again. Because on windows I used rear panel.

Here is my output for this command : `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`

Output:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device a102
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
    Memory at fbff4000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
   00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
```

and command `aplay -l`:

Output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 1: ALC889 Digital [ALC889 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I have also checked `alsamixer`:

[image: alsamixer capture output]

any can give any solutions?