# Acer Aspire VN7-592G no microphone under Ubuntu, Mint, Antergos

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, audio, antergos, acer

I have an Acer Aspire laptop model VN7-592G. I have had no luck in getting the microphone to work on it using Ubuntu 16.04, latest Mint, latest Antergos. In searching the web I don't think anyone else has had luck with this model under any Linux distro yet either in getting the microphone to work. From finding tips on the web, I've tried tweaking around in alsamixer, pulse audio controls, just like [this poster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99333/headphone-microphone-is-not-workinglinux-mint-15?rq=1) seems to but with no luck. In all the Linux distros I've tried, the speakers work, just not the microphone. The sound devices work perfectly fine under Windows 10.

Comment: Output of `cat /proc/asound/version`?

Comment: Is your sound card listed here `cat cat /proc/asound/cards`? You need to make sure that the appropriate driver module is loaded `lspci | egrep -i audio`

Answer (score 1):

An external headset works when I write in the file: `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

The following entries:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1523100/comments/52

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the audio drivers are loaded and working properly.
Just follow what has already been exposed here by *Erel Segal-Halevi*:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/508221/sound-input-device-microphone-not-working

1. Install pavucontrol: `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`
2. `sudo pavucontrol`
3. Go to the "Input Devices" tab & click the lock icon to unlock the channels
   Under "Port", select the correct microphone (front or rear)